# Display values from a matrix in a custom colormap (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, dictionary, colors, customization, colorbar

I want to visualize a matrix based on the values its contain. I have one cell, which contains 11 matrices, each matrix has 4 columns which are x,y,z (the coordinate) and its values. I want to visualize this value, with location x, y, z and define my own colormap based on those values then display the colorbar. I want to use jet as the colormap. I want to use Blue to describe the maximal value and Red as the minimal value on the colormap. The values between maximal and minimal values have a color between red to blue.

This is the code that I already tried:

```
figure;
hold on
for i=1:length(diameter_lca)
    L2 = diameter_lca{i};
    dl1 = find(L2(:,4) > minimal_lca & L2(:,4)<2);%diameter 0-2
    dl2 = find(L2(:,4) >= 2 & L2(:,4) <= maksimal_lca);%diameter>2-maksimal
    x=L2(:,1);
    y=L2(:,2);
    z=L2(:,3);
    plot3(y(dl1),x(dl1),z(dl1),'*','Color','r');
    plot3(y(dl2),x(dl2),z(dl2),'*','Color','b');
end
daspect([0.488281 0.488281 0.625000]);
view(3); axis tight
camlight
```

In those code above, what I do is visualize the values on the 4th column from each matrix then I made a condition which is if the value is between 0-2, I gave red, and when it is between 2-maximal value of the 4th column, I gave blue.

Now, I need to display each value from the 4th column from each matrix in colormap jet without any condition like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to use `scatter3`:

```
%# make jet colormap from red to blue
cmap = flipud(jet(128));

%# plot values
figure,
scatter3(L(:,1),L(:,2),L(:,3),[],L(:,4),'marker','*')

colormap(cmap)
colorbar
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much :). But i still have one more question. What if i want to display it as a line or use dash instead of asterisk (*)

Comment: In that case, you may want to download and use [cline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8597) from the Matlab File Exchange. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i accept your answer and upvoting it. Thank you so much. Oh that cline, I tried that too but the method that you gave me (scatter3) works better than the cline. I couldn't upload the result images in here, but i prefer your method. Thank you so much :)